# My macro only delete excel data not rows.I want delete rows as well

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro. In this it only removes data not rows. e.g. I have 600 000 records after macro it left 15 000 records, but my excel sheet shows 600 000 records - 15 000 records with data and rest empty, but I want it show only 15 000 records.

All empty rows should deleted.

Macro:

```
Sub DeleteRecord()
Dim MySheet As String
Dim cnt As Long
MySheet = ActiveSheet.Name
Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=33, Criteria1:= _
    ">=-.09", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=.01"
cnt = Worksheets(MySheet).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
If cnt > 3 Then Range("A2", ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Delete
Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=33
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below code. Deletes all the selected rows.

```
  Sub DeleteRecord()
        Dim MySheet As String
        Dim cnt As Long
        MySheet = ActiveSheet.Name
        Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=33, Criteria1:= _
            ">=-.09", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=.01"


        cnt = Worksheets(MySheet).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        If cnt > 3 Then Range("A2", ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=33
    End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for reply it delete the record empty records still exist.it still showing 15000 records with data and 6 lakhs records without data.This also not work for me

Comment: What do you mean by 6 lakh records without data ? And how does the presence of blank cells affect your output ?